# Asset Catalog Compiler Error In Xcode

Tags: xcode, delete-directory

I accidentally deleted the asset folder in my Xcode project to clear memory for the new Xcode update, what can I do to fix this issue? do I just create a new folder with the same name and add the assets back? I already emptied the trash.

Comment: if the deleted folder is still exits in trash then you can get it from there ..

Comment: Have you been version controlling with something like Git or Subversion?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have an assets in any other place even though Trash then need one 1024x1024 icon of your app to generate all assets also need to do following steps.

**If you had accidently deleted the app icons folder from image assets then it will be look like this.**

[image]

**please dont be panic now just clean your project using Cmd+Shift+Alt+K
then it will be seems like this**

**Now Click on use Asset Catalogue it will show the prompt like this.**

[image]

**Just click on Migrate
Now there is the appIcon is present**

[image]

**Just click on right arrow and right click on the appIcons**

[image]

**Now open it in finder and make the appicon assets using the app named "[Icon Set Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?mt=12)" which is Free on [appStore](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?mt=12).**

**Once you generated all icons replace the generated folder will existing one.**

Your all assets will be regenerated.

Comment: @Noah Iarrobino Is this Worked for you? If Yes Please make this answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted asset folder accidentally,Make sure its there in trash and replace it and add it again in xcode.If already deleted from trash also try to recover it using recovery tools.

Comment: trash has already been dumped, the file is completely gone, any advice on what to do from here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new asset catalog to your project just like any other file. Choose “New File...” and then select the template Asset Catalog under Resource, you may have to scroll down to see it. Then name it to something suitable.